# link error while trying to declare templated class State using std::function (Undefined symbols)

Tags: c++, templates, std-function

I defined a `State<>` template class to accept a universal `std::function<>` callable parameters list:

```
template <typename T> class State;

template <class RV, class... Args>
class State<RV(Args...)>
{
private:
    std::function<RV(Args...)> code = nullptr;

public:
    RV operator()() {
        return code();
    }

    void setCode(std::function<RV(Args...)> f) {
        code = f;
    }

    State();
    State(State&);
    State(State&&);
    State& operator=(State&);
    State& operator=(State&&);
    virtual ~State();

};
```

Now I'm trying to use it in module:

```
auto s = State<void(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)>();
```

to define a template instantiation, that would configure the internal `std::function` to accept a lambda with my parameters (`Touch`, `Event`)
But I get a linker error `Undefined symbols`:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "State<void (cocos2d::Touch*, cocos2d::Event*)>::State()", referenced from:
      UITableView::UITableView(cocos2d::Size, cocos2d::Vec2) in UITableView.o
  "State<void (cocos2d::Touch*, cocos2d::Event*)>::~State()", referenced from:
      UITableView::UITableView(cocos2d::Size, cocos2d::Vec2) in UITableView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Comment: And you do define the constructor and destructor functions? Where are you doing that?

Comment: On an unrelated note, your copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator should take its arguments as a reference to a *constant* `State`. I.e. `State const&` or `const State&`.

Comment: btw how shall I define the operators externally

Comment: template <class RV, class... Args>
State& State<RV(Args...)>::operator=(State<RV(Args...)>&) {
   
}

Comment: Like any other template function, and exactly like you show in your comment. Except that if you say a function will return something, you better have a `return` statement in the definition.

Comment: Another question. I want to define lambda in ctor so I declared    a ctor accepting std::function like this: State(std::function<RV(Args...)> f);
but when I try to use it like this: auto s = State<void(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)>([](cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event) ->void {});
compiler says 
Ambiguous conversion for functional-style cast from '(lambda at UITableView.cpp:41:72)' to 'State<void (cocos2d::Touch *, cocos2d::Event *)>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to define (not only declare) constructor and destructor for the class

```
State<>::State()
State<>::~State()
```

thanks to Some programmer dude for pointing this